# If $x^2$ is prime, then x is not a positive integer

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, prime-numbers

Prove the following statement using a technique (contrapositive or contradiction)

If $x^2$ is prime, then $x$ is not a positive integer

My attempt: suppose $X$ is positive integer for further I can't get any idea any one help.

Comment: Hint: Use contrapositive.

Comment: @JackyChong..it mean suppose x is positive the $x^2$ is not prime

Comment: Yes. Now prove the statement.

Comment: @JackyChong..how we start suppose $x^2$ is prime then how go next..

Comment: You should start by assuming $x$ is a positive integer.

Comment: @JackyChong...suppose x is positive integer then $x^2 $ is positive integer ..then Is we can say directly x^2 is not prime

Comment: @JackyChong..coz we cant be expressed as a prime is power of square

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47556/discussion-between-rajendra-and-jacky-chong).

Comment: @JackyChong...can you tell is am right are wrong

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/979211/the-square-root-of-a-prime-number-is-irrational

Answer (score 1):

Hint: obviously $$x|x^2.$$
But $x^2$ is prime, thus its only (integer) divisors are $1$ and $x^2$. Conclude